# python validation for string

Tags: python, string, validation

```
  try :
      productcategory = input("Enter product category :")
  except ValueError :
      print("Invalid input")
  else :
      if category ==  "meat" or "seafood" or "bakery" or "diary" or "fruits" :
          category[item] = productcategory
          break
      else:
          print("Please enter valid category")
```

hi guys i have been trying to limit my input to either meat , seafood,bakery,diary , fruits by performing validation however even though my input is not either of the following my program still takes the wrong input.

i would appreciate any help i can get thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `or` all the statements have to be separate

```
if category ==  "meat" or category == "seafood" or category == "bakery" or category == "diary" or category == "fruits"
```

alternate

```
try :
      productcategory = input("Enter product category :")
except ValueError :
    print("Invalid input")
else :
    if productcategory in [ "meat" , "seafood" , "bakery" , "diary" , "fruits"] :
        category[item] = productcategory
        # break #there is no loop
    else:
        print("Please enter valid category")
```